# install qcharts module to yocto sdk

Tags: c++, qt, yocto, bitbake, qtcharts

I try to cross-compile [qt chart example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtcharts-areachart-example.html) for a [yocto platform](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Main_Page). I do following steps to compile my qt programs:

- source /opt/myimage/2.1.2/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
- qmake -o Makefile areachart.pro
- make

But When I add `QT += charts` to any project run qmake like `qmake -o Makefile areachart.pro` I hit this error:
`Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: charts`

Here is the output of `qmake -v`:

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.7.0 in /opt/myimage/2.1.2/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib
```

Should I add `qtcharts` module my [yocto SDK](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html) to be able to compile the example? if yes how?

For some reasons I was able to cross-compiled [Qt from source](https://github.com/qt/qtcharts) using `qtcreator` and get the binary files for qt examples and qtchart library itself. I also run the qt examples on my target platform by putting resulting `libQtCharts.so` and other files manually in `/usr/lib/` and `/usr/include/` on the target and I was able to draw the charts on target.

However, what I need is to include the charts in my project and run `qmake` steps as mentioned above. But what I get is the `Project ERROR:  Unknown module(s) in QT: charts`
I have tried to put `libQtCharts.so` which I got from compiling qt source manually in `/opt/myimage/2.1.2/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib` but still not able to get the make file with `qmake -o Makefile areachart.pro`

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, you need `qtcharts` package (also with `qtcharts-dev` to be precise) in your SDK. You also need `qtcharts` package on your target (i.e. in your image), otherwise the runtime library will be missing when you will execute your binary on the target.

The addition of the package depends on the method of building the SDK. The preferred one is a `populate_sdk` task, so I will describe it here (it will also add the package to your target).

The command to build the SDK is `bitbake your_image -c populate_sdk`. Add  following lines to `your_image.bb` recipe to add the `qtcharts` package to the image (line 1) and other Qt5 stuff for SDK (line 2).

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "qtcharts"
inherit populate_sdk_qt5
```

You can also put these lines into `your_image.bbappend` if you don't want to edit the image recipe directly.

The `inherit populate_sdk_qt5` is specific (and required) for Qt5 packages, because other stuff is needed for SDK (e.g. `qt.conf`, some tools).

Comment: thanks. I have used both methods the `qcharts` is added to my target image so I can execute binaries with qchart. But the actual problem is not solved, I think qcharts still is not added to the SDK. I have added `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " qtcharts"` to bb file then `bitbake myimage -c populate_sdk` finally `bitbake myimage` but still no trace of libQt5Chart.so etc in /opt/myimage/../usr/lib. The last thing I did is `bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5` and run the generate script to install sdk in /opt/myimage/... What I am missing here? it looks basic task to add a new library/module to sdk.

Comment: I just noticed that I have two sdks in tmp/deploy/sdk: `myimage-glibc-x86_64-core-image-myimage-cortexa9hf-neon-toolchain-2.1.2.sh` and `myimage-glibc-x86_64-meta-toolchain-qt5-cortexa9hf-neon-toolchain-2.1.2.sh` so my question to which recipe should I add qtcharts how to have qtcharts on meta-toolchain-qt5 sdk? because I need to compile my program with qmake here `/opt/myimage/2.1.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/qt5/qmake`

Comment: @PHA meta-toolchain-qt5 is a different method and the IMAGE_INSTALL in my answer won't help here (I see your new question, I will try to answer on Monday). Could you please check the `xxx.target.manifest` files in the `tmp/deploy/sdk` directory? They should contain qtcharts. If not, the qtcharts are definitelly not part of the new SDK. If yes, something with installation of your SDK is wrong.

Comment: @PHA sorry, I totally forgot `inherit populate_sdk_qt5` line in the image recipe. It is required for Qt5 based SDK. I've checked our Qt5 SDK and I don't see any other thing, so I hope that this is all...