# Yocto: Properly adding support for Qt5 modules with meta-qt5

Tags: qt5, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, imx6

## Context

I'd like to run a Qt application on an IM6 based system with a Yocto built image. I already have the `meta-qt5` layer in my project. I started with a simple Qt5 application that only neededs the following modules:

```
QT += core gui widgets
```

All I have to do is make sure my bitbake recipe has `DEPENDS += qtbase` and is based on the qmake class with: `inherit qmake5`. And it builds and runs on the target! No problem

---

## Problem

Now I'd like to add another Qt5 application, this time with the following modules and one plugin:

```
QT += core gui widgets    quick qml svg xml network charts
QTPLUGIN += qsvg
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to simple add these to my `DEPENDS` variable and get it to work. But googling around for how to add support reveals what seems to be a sprawling assortment of solutions. I'll enumerate what I've found here:

1. I need to add `inherit populate_sdk_qt5` to instruct bitbake to build the **recipe** against the SDK that contains the libraries for the modules (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258161/how-do-i-get-qt-sdk-configured-properly-with-yocto-project))
2. I need to add `IMAGE_FEATURES += dev-pkgs` to the **recipe** (see [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/meta-freescale/2014-May/008435.html))
3. I need to modify `local.conf` for the **system**, and add lines like: `PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn_qttools = "..."` and *also* `PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtbase = "..."`
4. I need to modify `layer.conf` in my **layer** and add things like `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "qtbase qtquick ..."` (slide 53 [here](https://www.slideshare.net/MarcoCavallini1/run-qt-on-linux-embedded-systems-using-yocto))
5. I need to manually patch the Qt5 toolchain for charts? (see [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2018-February/039952.html))
6. I need to compile my image using `bitbake <target> -c populate_sdk`? (see [here again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258161/how-do-i-get-qt-sdk-configured-properly-with-yocto-project))

At this point, I'm really unsure what exactly is going on. It seems we're modifying the recipe, the layer configuration file, the distribution configuration file, and even meta-Qt layer files. I know that I fundamentally need to do a few things:

1. Compile the application against the Qt5 SDK
2. Compile the needed plugins + modules for the target architecture
3. Make sure the appropriate binaries (images) are copied to the target.

But it has become a bit unclear about what does what. I know that `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` adds images to the target, but I am lost with what is the proper way to add the modules. I don't want to go about randomly adding lines, so I'm hoping someone can clear up a bit what exactly I need to be looking at in order to add support for a Qt5 module for an application.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661447/install-qcharts-module-to-yocto-sdk ?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk I can attempt what was done in the answer, but the OP did not signal it worked for them (did not mark question answered and comments inconclusive). Is this a method you believe will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different problems stated, your preferred way seems to the directly building a recipe, not using the toolchain. So, you need the image to have the tools you need.

First of all `qtsvg` **is not** on Qt Base, it is a module so you need it installed.

#### Add Qt SVG support

You need Qt SVG on target in order to run your App. Either to your `image` or to `local.conf` you need

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " qtsvg"
```

As a fact, your app's recipe **needs** Qt QSVG so you need to `DEPEND` on it on your app's recipe like this:

```
DEPENDS = "qtsvg"
```

here `qtsvg` is the name of the other recipe, namely `qtsvg_git.bb`, not to be confused with the identically named `qtsvg` plugin. And it will get pulled automatically on build time on your development machine, otherwise it won't even build.

Remember yocto creates a simulated image tree on the `TMP` folder in order to build (yes it does it for **each** recipe), so you must describe what your recipe needs or it won't find it and your build will fail.

You can also check [the recipe for a Qt5 example](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5/blob/master/recipes-qt/examples/qt5ledscreen_1.0.bb) as it also has `DEPENDS` and `RDEPENDS`. And you can get more [info on those in here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/rdepends-v-s-depends-in-yocto/).

Comment: Almost a year later but better than never. Thanks Ariel!